# What are the vertical and horizontal asymptotes for the function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can recognize polynomials of the form p(x)/q(x) and identify the vertical and horizontal asymptotes. However, in a case like this one which doesn't involve polynomial functions, how do I identify what types of asymptotes are present and what are they?
$$
    \frac {(x^2+3x+2)\tan(\pi x)}{x+2}$$
Also can you suggest a good read for asymptotes analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what do you know about the $\tan$ function?  What does its graph look like?